# Bash script parsing argument with quotes

Tags: shell-script, quoting

Please consider this simple script named *test*:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo $1
```

and the following commands and calls:

```
$ echo "A B"
A B
$ echo ""A B""
A B
$ echo """A B"""
A B
$ echo """A B"""
A B

$ ./test "A B"
A B
$ ./test ""A B""
A
$ ./test """A B"""
A B
$ ./test """"A B""""
A
```

Could someone please explain why the call of *test* doens't behave like the command *echo* or point to the relevant documentation?

Comment: There is already a *test* command, you are lucky you were using the full path, otherwise you would have had a tough time debugging the situation.

Comment: Better for this kind of test is to use `printf '%q\n' "$@"` instead of `echo` at all, which will emit your arguments one-to-a-line with hidden characters and whitespace escaped in a visible form.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Because `echo` concatenates **all** it arguments to print them, and your script is limited to the **first** argument. You should use `"$@"` and not `$1` in your script.

Let's look at the arguments you're providing for your tests:

- `./test "A B"`

  - one argument, the 3 character string <kbd>A</kbd><kbd>space</kbd><kbd>B</kbd>
- `./test ""A B""`

  - two arguments

    - first, <kbd>empty string</kbd> concatenated with <kbd>A</kbd>
    - second, <kbd>B</kbd> concatenated with <kbd>empty string</kbd>
- `./test """A B"""`

  - one argument, <kbd>empty string</kbd> concatenated with <kbd>A</kbd><kbd>space</kbd><kbd>B</kbd> concatenated with <kbd>empty string</kbd>
- `./test """"A B""""`

  - two arguments

    - first, <kbd>empty string</kbd> concatenated with <kbd>empty string</kbd> concatenated with <kbd>A</kbd>
    - second, <kbd>B</kbd> concatenated with <kbd>empty string</kbd> concatenated with <kbd>empty string</kbd>

Note: you would see different results from `echo` if you had used more than one space in your arguments. That's because echo concatenates its arguments with a single space:

```
$ echo "A   B"
A   B
$ echo ""A   B""
A B
$ echo """A   B"""
A   B
$ echo """"A   B""""
A B
```

Comment: those are neat little *empty string* doodads.

Comment: exactly, quotes don't nest...